# Unable to assign value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble trying to assign a value to a "Grocery List"

Specifically, given a .txt doc, which contains:

```
Grocery
Apple: 12
egg: 10
milk: 11
```

I am trying to open the file, and compute the total price for it. What I have so far:

```
shoplist={}
line=0

for item in open ("lab3demo.txt","r"):
    item= item.split(":")

    line+=1
    if line ==1:
        continue

    print (item)
```

So far it does return `['Apple',12\r\n']`, etc.

However, I am then trying to assign the price as a value `price = shoplist[item]`, which does not work. Since I need it to output the

```
item : price
item : price
item : price
total: total price
```

which I am not able to do. What should I be looking to do so?

I have tried starting as a dictionary, but haven't got too far.

Comment: I don't understand what "trying to assign the price as a value". If you want to add the item-price pair to the dict, you just got things backward: `shoplist[item] = price`, but you also have to put the two splits into those two variables, `item, price = item.split(':')`, before you can use those variables. I'm not sure if that's what you want or not, however.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're trying to do is:

- Split the line into `item` and `price` variables.
- Add that into the dict, with `item` as the key, and `price` as the corresponding value.

If so, you got two things wrong. First, here:

```
item= item.split(":")
```

This just makes `item` into a pair of two values. You wanted those two values in two separate variables, `item` and `price`, so you have to tell Python that:

```
item, price = item.split(":")
```

And then:

> I am then trying to assign the price as a value `price = shoplist[item]`

You've got that backward. That would look up `item` in `shoplist`, and store the resulting value in `price`. But you want to *add* the `item` and `price` to `shoplist`:

```
shoplist[item] = price
```

Having done that, at the end of the loop, you'll have a dict like this:

```
{'Apple': '12', 'egg': '10', 'milk': '11'}
```

You still need to work out how to:

- Loop over each `item` and `price` in the `items` of `shoplist`.
- Print out each `item` and `price` in the right format.
- Convert each `price` from a string to an `int`.
- Add each `price` value to a `total`
- Print out the `total` after that loop in the right format.

But you should be able to get that all working.